# Django combine REMOTE_USER auth with LDAP checks

Tags: python, django

I recently got LDAP authentication working with the django-auth-ldap module. That got me thinking, since this is being run behind IIS in an Active Directory environment, that there should be a way to do single sign-on. It looks like using the RemoteUserMiddleware you can do single sign-on using the REMOTE_USER environment variable. But problem is I need to lock this down to a small handful of users in an AD group. I'm a Django n00b so I'm having trouble wraping my head around how I would glue the two system together in order to get the user from REMOTE_USER and then do an LDAP lookup to AD to check group membership. And Google is failing me. Has anyone done anything like this before?

Comment: It's looking like maybe I keep the settings in settings.py for django-auth-ldap. Remove that as an authentication backend and then create a custom authentication backend using the RemoteUserBackend class from RemoteUserMiddleware and the LDAPBackend class from django-auth-ldap.

Comment: Not sure how I get request.META['REMOTE_USER'] in my authentication backend since that info is in the HTTP request...